# How to extend SQLalchemy Base class with a static method

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have multiple classes similar to the following:

```
class Weather(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Weather"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    temperature = Column(Integer)
    humidity = Column(Integer)
    wind_speed = Column(Float)
    wind_direction = Column(String)
```

I want to add a method `df()` that returns me the Pandas dataframe of that table. I know I can write it like this:

```
class Weather(Base):
   __tablename__ = "Weather"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    temperature = Column(Integer)
    humidity = Column(Integer)
    wind_speed = Column(Float)
    wind_direction = Column(String)

    @staticmethod
    def df():
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            return pd.read_sql_table(Weather.__tablename__ , conn)
```

But I want to implement this for every table. I guess if I can extend the Base class with this method I should be able to implement it once and use it in every class. Everything I have tried has failed because I do not have access to `__tablename__`  attribute.

**SOLUTION**
I ended up with a mix of both answers. I have used the first method proposed by [@snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) (it allows to introduce the change without modifying the rest of the code) with the `@classmethod` proposed by [@RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest) (which is the bit I was missing).

```
class MyBase:
    __tablename__ = None

    @classmethod
    def df(cls):
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            return pd.read_sql_table(cls.__tablename__ , conn)

Base = declarative_base(cls=MyBase)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an auxiliary class (say `DfBase`) with [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) `df(cls)` having the desired behavior.
Then each derived class will access its `__tablename__` attribute seamlessly via `cls` object which refers to the derived class itself.

```
class DfBase:
    __tablename__ = None

    @classmethod
    def df(cls):
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            return pd.read_sql_table(cls.__tablename__ , conn)


class Weather(Base, DfBase):
    __tablename__ = "Weather"
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by passing a [custom class to the declarative_base](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.declarative_base.params.cls) function:

```py
class MyBase:
    __abstract__ = True

    @staticmethod
    def df():
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            return pd.read_sql_table(Weather.__tablename__ , conn)

Base = orm.declarative_base(cls=MyBase)

class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl'
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can create a mixin that provides the static method and have classes inherit from it selectively.

```py
class DFMixin:
    @staticmethod
    def df():
        with engine.connect() as conn:
            return pd.read_sql_table(Weather.__tablename__ , conn)

class MyModel(Base, DFMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl'
    ...
```

The mixin gives you more flexibility if not all of your models are going to need the dataframe functionality.

Comment: I assume that I also have to change the name of the class inside the parameters of pd.read_sql_table. The problem is that by doing so I get the error `type object 'MyBase' has no attribute '__tablename__'`

Comment: If you do `Base = orm.declarative_base(cls=MyBase)` then your model classes must inherit from _Base_.